# Is it possible to disable null values from firebase events in Big Query?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, events

Is it possible to disable or completely ignore the null values in BigQuery that come from firebase events of a (mobile) app?

***Example:***

*key =>* `my_custom_firebase_event:`

*value =>* `{"string_value": null, "int_value": "123456789", "doube_value":null}`

***Preferred:***

value => `{"int_value": "123456789"}`

[image]

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the functions [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays) to save into an array and [OFFSET](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest_and_with_offset) to get each value from the array.

You can see this query with the same example of your post.

```
WITH sample AS (
 SELECT JSON_QUERY('{"raw_result":{"string_value": null, "int_value": "123456789", "doube_value":null}}', '$.raw_result') json
),
sample2 as (
 
SELECT concat(K ,v)  as int_value
 FROM sample as t,
      UNNEST(bqutil.fn.json_extract_keys(json)) k WITH OFFSET ki,
      UNNEST(bqutil.fn.json_extract_values(json)) v WITH OFFSET vi
WHERE ki = vi and k='int_value'
 
)
 
select TO_JSON_STRING(t) from sample2 as t
```

This was the output.

[image]